# How to change the name of the application on the main page on xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to change this white text on the main page?

I read the documentation and found out what needs to be changed in Values - Strings.xml. I changed but nothing has changed.

[image]

code from strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Diseases</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Check out AndroidManifest.xaml and also the attributes above MainActivity.cs class.

Comment: i could not repeat your issue,try to clean your solution and rebuild it

Comment: @VahidShir I already did all this and did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places that this could be coming from possibly the first.

First would be the attributes of your Activity, Assuming the page in the image is your MainActivity.

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", ...)]
  public class MainActivity : ...
```

Change the `Label` Property

Or in your `AndroidManifest` file if you have this activity declared there something like

```
<activity
 android:name="com.example.appname.MainActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Where `com.example.appname` is the package name

Comment: second solution helped